# How do I use a mysql db after creation with terminal?

Tags: mysql, database, macos, terminal

I have created a mysql database and a table on terminal. The data is stored in /usr/local/mysql but my db is a folder and a table has .ibd extension.

How do I get a normal .db extension with a table inside?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What "normal db extension" are you talking about? Why are you even interested in the /usr/local/mysql folder? You should talk to the database using the SQL protocol, from a client (such as the CLI that you already used, or an SQL workbench app, or your own program, etc)

Comment: I need to open this database on a different machine, so it should have a .database extension. Now it's just a folder.

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you mean. It's fine as it is. Why you do think it needs to be a file with a .db extension? You shouldn't care about how it's stored, that's an irrelevant implementation detail for most intents and purposes. If you want to access it on a different machine, either connect from the other machine to your mysql server on this machine, or export the data as sql file, transfer it to the new machine and import it into another mysql instance there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.db` file extension is normally used by SQLite, which is a different database product than MySQL.

SQLite is an embedded database. You can write client programs that use the SQLite library to read and write `.db` files. But it's limited to read and write files that are located on the same computer where your client program runs.

MySQL is a client/server database. You shouldn't read and write the data file directly. The only program that does that is `mysqld`, the MySQL Server daemon.

You can write applications that use the MySQL client library to open a socket or TCP/IP connection to convey commands to the MySQL Server. This allows the MySQL Server to be on a different computer than where your client program runs. Your client program can request data remotely, over a network. Likewise, other client programs on yet other computers can also make network connections to the MySQL Server's computer. It supports many remote connections at the same time.

You should probably learn more about using MySQL. The manual has a [tutorial section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tutorial.html).

Comment: Okay, I got the difference, then I need an SQLite. Thank you!